# Bind more than one command to single key in screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

how can i bind more than one command to a single key in gnu-screen? I want to combine the two mappings

```
bind c copy
bind b eval "writebuf" "exec sh -c 'xsel --clipboard < /tmp/screen-exchange'"
```

to a single one-key mapping. How can this be done?

Does anyone know a good tutorial on this advanced configuration/scripting stuff for gnu-screen?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass each command as a separate argument to `eval`, e.g., `eval "echo foo" "echo bar"`. In your given scenario, I would think that just adding `copy` after `eval` would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Arkku, but that doesn't work for me. If i use "bind c eval "copy" "writebuf" "exec sh -c 'xsel --clipboard < /tmp/screen-exchange'" only the copy commands seems to be executed. No change to "/tmp/screen-exchange" is made.

Comment: It seems that `copy` may interrupt the processing. Try adding `echo`s before and after each command so you can see how the command progresses; in my quick test it seemed that entering the copy/scrollback mode interrupts it.

Comment: It seems that only if i don't press any key the whole command sequence is executed and an empty copy written to /tmp/screen... If i press RETURN to set the first mark, the whole sequence is interrupted.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if there's any way around that.

Comment: O.k., then i will live with my two key bindings. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
     bind \# eval focus "resize 130"
```

for example to switch between two vertical split windows and resize, at the same time, the focused window to 130 columns (pressing "`C-A #`").

So, the concatenation of multiple commands with '`eval`' seems to work properly.