# Is there a way to initiate UNIX screen with keyboard commands?

Tags: linux, unix, command, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

Is there a way to begin a screen session with keyboard commands?

For instance I want to start screen, split the window horizontally, and then switch to the bottom window with one command. Currently I can only start screen and then running the keyboard commands:

Split vertically: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd>.

Switch screen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd>.

Is there a way I can do this with one line when starting a new screen session? Or a work around to simulate pressing keyboard commands once screen is started?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the following lines into `.screenrc`:

```
split
focus
screen
```

Or even:

```
bind U eval split focus screen
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793231/1088827).

Comment: I definitely think this answer should be accepted: it is correct, clear, straight to the point and I think it's impossible to provide a better answer.